# Best use of Jquery sliders and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have two questions:

- What's the best way to send sliders' values to a PHP page ? I'm associating each slider (several per page) with an hidden form so far, but I wonder if there's a "cleaner" way to do this.
- Related to the 1st question; I've some trouble with the script:

  ```
   var score = $(this).slider( "option", "value" );
   $(this).closest("input[type=='hidden']").val(score);
  ```

It doesn't set the value of the hidden input. Can somebody tells me what's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: it should work, so to see what went wrong you should post a more complete example

Comment: I have nothing more. I just have a table; each <tr> contains a <td> with a slider (id ='r#') and an hidden input (id='i#').

Comment: are you sure the `.closest("input[type=='hidden']")` is actually fetching your input?

Comment: Actually no, but i can't see how to verify if it's the problem. It seems so tricky to manipulate hidden inputs. I just took the code I found on Jquery website.

Comment: Just do : alert($(this).closest("input[type='hidden']"));

Comment: It just returns [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found something that works, even if it's probably not the cleanest way to do:

I added a class .slideVal to the hidden input and here's the JS code:

```
            $('.slider').live("mouseup",function(){
                var score = $(this).slider( "option", "value" );
                $(this).closest("tr").find(".slideVal").val(score);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the following is not correct in your CSS selector :

```
input[type=='hidden']
```

Replace it by :

```
input[type='hidden']
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the method `closest` is misleading.

It returns the first **ancestor** (parents parents parent etc), that matches the given selector.

You can think of it being equivalent to `$(this).parents('.slideVal:first')`.

Hopefully it's beginning to sink in why your example isn't working!